# @AfterMapping is not called from @Mapper interface

Tags: java, mapstruct

I'm having trouble using Mapstruct.

I am using a `@Mapper` annotated interface with `@AfterMapping` inside like follow:

```
@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public interface ConfiguracionReautorizacionMapper {

    ConfiguracionReautorizacionDTO toConfiguracionReautorizacionDTO(final ConfiguracionReautorizacion configuracionReautorizacion);

    ConfiguracionReautorizacion toConfiguracionReautorizacion(final ConfiguracionReautorizacionDTO configuracionReautorizacionDTO);

    @AfterMapping
    default void fillServiciosAsociados(@MappingTarget final ConfiguracionReautorizacionDTO configuracionReautorizacionDTO, final ConfiguracionReautorizacion configuracionReautorizacion) {
        configuracionReautorizacionDTO.setTieneRolesOServiciosAsociados(!(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(configuracionReautorizacion.getRolesAplicacionEdesk()) && CollectionUtils.isEmpty(configuracionReautorizacion.getRolesAplicacionEdesk())));
    }

}
```

The mapper works perfectly but the `@AfterMapping`method is never called. 
I read other post that shows examples using `abstract class` instead of `interface`.

Is using `abstract class` mandatory for use `@AfterMapping` annotation?

Comment: Are you using Lombok by any chance?

Comment: Yes, I'm using lombok, And I gues that my problem is by using lombok's builder with Mapstruct @Filip

Answer (score 38):

You can't pass the object (that is assumed to be immutable). You should pass the builder.. like this:

```java
@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public interface ConfiguracionReautorizacionMapper {

    ConfiguracionReautorizacionDTO toConfiguracionReautorizacionDTO(final ConfiguracionReautorizacion configuracionReautorizacion);

    ConfiguracionReautorizacion toConfiguracionReautorizacion(final ConfiguracionReautorizacionDTO configuracionReautorizacionDTO);

    @AfterMapping
    default void fillServiciosAsociados(@MappingTarget final ConfiguracionReautorizacionDTO.Builder configuracionReautorizacionDTO, final ConfiguracionReautorizacion configuracionReautorizacion) {
        configuracionReautorizacionDTO.setTieneRolesOServiciosAsociados(!(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(configuracionReautorizacion.getRolesAplicacionEdesk()) && CollectionUtils.isEmpty(configuracionReautorizacion.getRolesAplicacionEdesk())));
    }

}
```

Checkout out MapStruct [issue 1556](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1556).. You can also disable builders from 1.3.1 onwards

Comment: This one solved my issue. I had to remove @Builder annotation from my class.

Comment: @Clawdidr This could be an answer: so the ` @Builder` annotation make mapstruct `@AfterMapping` fail !

Comment: thanks. this work for my case. but it's useless when we pass builder to aftermapping, i need to update base class not builder one

Answer (score 20):

It is a bug when using `Lombok#@Builder` and `Mapstruct@AfterMapping`

Please use this situation `@BeanMapping(builder = @Builder(disableBuilder = true))`.

see https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1556#issuecomment-1011493330

Comment: It also works if you using `@Mapper`. The following worked for me
`@Mapper(builder = @Builder(disableBuilder = true))`

Comment: @jluiz20, this works with me, thanks

Answer (score 7):

When you are using Lombok builder and mapstruct together. @AfterMapping is not much useful though you pass a Builder object, since we can't retrieve the processed values. Instead I have used the custom method in my mapper to resolve this issue.

```
@Mapping(target ="field", expression = "java(customMethod(obj))")
```

this solved my use case, hope it helps others too.

Comment: interesting, though you can only access input params and not work on your target object with already mapped values as in @AfterMapping, which I need to finalize a collection from other mapped values.

Comment: That's an Interesting requirement though but I am not sure for your use case. Post me if you got to solve this use case.

Comment: In the end, I removed the builder because it was the cleanest solution and the builder was only used in some test code.

Comment: If you're using lombok with mapstruct on the same beans, you have to use lombok-mapstruct-binding. Just add it as a dependency to your project and it will work. For more info: https://mapstruct.org/faq/#Can-I-use-MapStruct-together-with-Project-Lombok

Answer (score 3):

This is specified in the mapstruct documentation. In the case of an @AfterMapping with a lombok builder, you should use the builder for the parameter with the @MappingTarget annotation. At the end of the linked paragraph: https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#customizing-mappings-with-before-and-after  :

> Important: when using a builder, the @AfterMapping annotated method must have the builder as @MappingTarget annotated parameter so that the method is able to modify the object going to be build. The build method is called when the @AfterMapping annotated method scope finishes. MapStruct will not call the @AfterMapping annotated method if the real target is used as @MappingTarget annotated parameter.

Comment: this is the correct solution when using ´@lombok.Builder´, the method annotated with ´@AfterMapper´ should have as input param ´@MappingTarget´ ClassName.ClassNameBuilder

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments the issue is because you are likely using Lombok Builder annotation for ConfiguracionReautorizacionDTO and ConfiguracionReautorizacion and possibly any of the nested classes of these classes. AfterMapping functionality does not play well with Lombok Builder. Again Lombok generally works with MapStruct, it seems Builder annotation is a specific issue. See if you can create the classes without using Builder annotation and then AfterMapping functionality should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

if you use lombok you must pass the Builder to the afterMapping method instead of the DTO itself. this should work for you:

```
@AfterMapping
default void fillServiciosAsociados(@MappingTarget ConfiguracionReautorizacionDTO.ConfiguracionReautorizacionDTOBuilder builder, final ConfiguracionReautorizacion configuracionReautorizacion) {
    builder.tieneRolesOServiciosAsociados(!(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(configuracionReautorizacion.getRolesAplicacionEdesk()) && CollectionUtils.isEmpty(configuracionReautorizacion.getRolesAplicacionEdesk())));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment but can't fit in the comment section.

If someone is gonna use @raji's answer, you must pay attention to the name of the variable you pass to `customMethod`

instead of `obj` you must put the name of the variable in your mapper method.

for Example:

```
@Mapping(target ="name", expression = "java(resolveName(userModel))")
UserDTO toDTO(User userModel);


default String resolveName(final User model) {
    return String.format("%s %s", model.firstName, model.lastName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Sjaak answer which is the legit answer. For my case this worked:

```
 myAfterMapping(...,@MappingTarget MyBean.MyBeanBuilder<?, ?> myBean,...){
 myBean.id(someValue);
 }
```

MyBeanBuilder is autogenerated (@Builder).